# Custom Mail Client for WebHost

Tags: html, css, email, web, client

I am currently using bluehost as a webhost for my website, but I am not a fan of their email client.  When I log into their mail client it presents me with three options to use and they are all rather unappealing (visually)...

Is there a way that I can make mail.MYURL.com and create my own custom mail client?

I have searched the web and couldn't find anything, but there should be a way...

If I needed to I could use php & javascript, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: yes, there is a way. But that would be a rather big project just to have a personal mail client. Try to install a fat client like Thunderbird when you don't like the web client of your provider. This question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. There are a lot of webmail implementation (in form of web apps, think Wordpress) such as Squirrelmail or Roundcube.

Serverfreak does a visual comparison of popular webmail clients here:

http://wow.serverfreak.com/2011/webmail-squirrelmail-roundcube-horde/

Those webmails typically requires  server side scripting (such as PHP) and POP3/IMAP support to retrieve your mail. Both are pretty much standard features for a webhost. So if you are comfortable of setting up web apps, things shouldn't be that hard.

That said you're using Bluehost which happens to use CPanel. CPanel offers various webmail options readily chosen at your disposal.

See Bluehost official guide on how to use them:
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/webmail

Alternatively, since you are concerned about visual appeal, you can always use desktop e-mail client such as Thunderbird/Outlook, or even use popular webmail such as GMail (via Google Apps) and Windows Live Mail (via Live hosted mail) mapped to your own domain name.